# Oauth, Net::Twitter, or SSL: 500 handshakefailed

Tags: perl, twitter, oauth

I copied a working Perl script that uses Net::Twitter from a 10.04 Ubuntu system to a 12.04 Ubuntu system.  It's not working anymore.

I'm now getting the following error at runtime:
Net::Twitter::Role::OAuth::get_authorization_url(): GET https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token failed: 500 handshakefailed at ok.pl line 22

When I try to curl the URL, I get this:
curl https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token
Failed to validate oauth signature and token

That seems to show I'm getting through the firewall and web proxy fine. Here's an example of one of the scripts.  All of my Twitter scripts get this 500 error now.  I've spent hours looking for a fix though and I'm still at a loss over whether this is an SSL issue with the module or if it's a connection issue with Twitter.

FWIW, the Net::Twitter on my 12.04 box is current.  The Net:Twitter on my 10.04 box is not current.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Net::Twitter;
my $tweet = 'Greetings';
my $twitterconsumer = 'redacted';
my $twitterconsumersecret = 'redacted';
my $youraccesstoken;
my $youraccesstokensecret;
my $twitteraccesstoken = $youraccesstoken;
my $twitteraccesstokensecret = $youraccesstokensecret;

my $nt = Net::Twitter->new(
    traits   => [qw/API::RESTv1_1/, 'OAuth'],
    consumer_key    => $twitterconsumer,
    consumer_secret => $twitterconsumersecret,
    ssl => 1
);
if ($twitteraccesstoken && $twitteraccesstokensecret) 
{
    $nt->access_token($twitteraccesstoken);
    $nt->access_token_secret($twitteraccesstokensecret);
}
unless ( $nt->authorized ) 
{
    print "Authorize this app at ", $nt->get_authorization_url, " and enter the PIN#\n";

    my $pin = <>; # wait for input
    chomp $pin;

    my($access_token, $access_token_secret, $user_id, $screen_name) = $nt->request_access_token(verifier => $pin);
    print 'Access token: '.$access_token."\r\n".'Access Token Secret: '.$access_token_secret."\r\n";

    exit();

}

$nt->update({ status => $tweet });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, after running a pcap of the traffic, I found out that the new system was getting blocked by a filter. It wasn't a problem with the module or my script.